# Reflection : can't get List "ElementAt" MethodInfo

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to get the MethodInfo for the method "ElementAt" of a List.

```
MethodInfo method = obj.GetType().GetMethod("ElementAt");
```

But then, "method" is 'null'. 
I tried to loop on each interfaces but the result is the same :

```
MethodInfo method = obj.GetType().GetMethod("ElementAt");
        if (method == null)
        {
            foreach (Type type in obj.GetType().GetInterfaces())
            {
                method = type.GetMethod("ElementAt");
                if (method != null)
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Enumerable.ElementAt<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int index)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) is a static extension method.

Comment: Hm, if I have a List<string> strings, I can invoke strings.ElementAt(0) without having to specify the array. (Unlike the method Enumerable.ElementAt(strings, 0))

Comment: The compiler just creates the illusion for you that ElementAt is a part of List<string>. It really isn't. `strings.ElementAt(0)` will be translated into `Enumerables.ElementAt(strings, 0)`.

Comment: Ok, I see. So, how can I get the first element of my array using reflection ? Does any method exists to do so ?

Comment: @abecker Maybe with the [Array.GetValue method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zexc3z9.aspx).

Comment: @abecker: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx  Use the indexer.